# Pointer to Incomplete Class type not allowed

Tags: c

I am implementing a bubble sort function, where it sorts words. the swap function words perfectly fine but i am unable to get the error. Tried searching online but could not get somthing useful. I have marked where i get the error.

Thank you for the help.

```
void sortWord (struct node** head) {
    struct node* temp  = (*head);
    struct node* temp2 = (*head);

    int i;
    int j;
    int counter = 0;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next; //<-- this is where i get the error.
        counter++;
    }
    for( i = 1; i<counter; i++)
    {
        temp2=(*head);
        for(j = 1; j<counter-1;j++)
        {
            if(wordCompare(temp2,nodeGetNextNode(temp2))>0)
            {
                swap(head,temp2,nodeGetNextNode(temp2));
                continue;
            }
        }
        temp2 = nodeGetNextNode(temp2);
    }
}
```

Comment: just use void* for next, not a specific struct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This error is given when you are trying to use a `struct` that has been forward-declared, but not *defined*. While it is absolutely OK to declare and manipulate *pointers* to such structs, trying to dereference them is not OK, because the compiler needs to know their size and layout in order to perform the access.

Specifically, in your case the compiler does not know that `struct node` has `next`, so

```
temp->next
```

does not compile.

You need to include a definition of the `struct node` in the compilation unit where you define your `sortWord` function to fix this problem.

Comment: That would work but will inflect on the generic of this code. using `nodeGetNextNode` instead will allow to leave this function as is. and when `node` structure will change he only need to update the "callbacks" (if I can call them that in C): `nodeGetNextNode`, `wordCompare` and `swap`.

Answer (score 6):

You should replace this line:

```
temp = temp->next;
```

with that line:

```
temp = nodeGetNextNode(temp);
```

The reason is that in this code you know nothing about the structure of `node`. I guess that's why you used `nodeGetNextNode` function for temp2. you just need to used it for temp as well.

Comment: @Manmohit If this is what you did, you should put the checkmark here. And do it soon… since you previously checked it, a 5-minute countdown started.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: thanks for the care. But as long as the problem solved I'm happy (: